# Why is phosphoric acid preferentially used for dehydrating alcohols during synthesis of alkenes?

Tags: synthesis

I have also seen concentrated sulphuric acid being used, but what makes phosphoric acid preferable to sulfuric acid?

Comment: Sulphuric acid can also act as an oxidant, phosphoric cannot.

Comment: Ohh, thanks! Also, does the concentration of acid matter?

Comment: Phosphoric acid is most often used as polyphosphoric acid which is a thick syrup. This is essentially neat phosphoric acid, which can be made stronger by addition of P2O5.